# java.net.SocketException socket is closed un expectively in android

Tags: java, android, sockets

here is my thread for tcp server

```
class Tcpserver implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try
            {
                m_server=new ServerSocket(2001);
                Log.v("tcp", "srvrsckt crtd");
                final Socket connectedsocket=m_server.accept();
                Log.v("tcp", "client cnctd");
                Message clientmessage=Message.obtain();
                Log.v("tcp", "clnt msg obtain");
                ObjectInputStream ois= new ObjectInputStream(connectedsocket.getInputStream());
                String strMessage=(String) ois.readObject();
                clientmessage.obj=strMessage;
                Log.v("tcp", "b4 call handlr");
                mHandler.sendMessage(clientmessage);

                Log.v("tcp", "o/p stm obtain");
                Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try { Socket connectedsocketdup=connectedsocket;
                            Log.v("tcp","socketcrtdonclick");
                            ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(connectedsocketdup.getOutputStream());
                            Log.v("tcp","tcpsrvronclick");
                            oos.writeObject("Hai....mmx");
                            //oos.writeChars("hi...mmx");
                            Log.v("tcp","write");
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            Log.v("tcp","error"+e);
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                Log.v("tcp", "write");
                ois.close();
                //oos.close();
                m_server.close();
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Message msg3=Message.obtain();
                msg3.obj=e.getMessage();
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg3);
            }
        }
    }
```

when i called the on click fn by click the button then the error

> java.net.SocketException socket is closed

is obtained

the log cat is given below
*

> 03-29 04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   V/tcp﹕ socketcrtdonclick 03-29 04:50:11.530
>   3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker V/tcp﹕
>   errorandroid.widget.EditText@40573ab0 03-29 04:50:11.530
>   3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker W/System.err﹕
>   java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed 03-29 04:50:11.530
>   3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.checkNotClosed(PlainSocketImpl.java:140)
>   03-29 04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.getOutputStream(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
>   03-29 04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.getOutputStream(Socket.java:453)
>   03-29 04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker.Wall$Tcpserver$1.onClick(Wall.java:237)
>   03-29 04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485) 03-29
>   04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
>   03-29 04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   03-29 04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   03-29 04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 03-29
>   04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3714) 03-29
>   04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-29 04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   03-29 04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
>   03-29 04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611) 03-29
>   04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132) 03-29
>   04:50:11.530    3482-3482/com.example.pranavtv.loudspeaker
>   W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

*

Comment: This is broken on many levels - in addition to trying to asynchronously utilize a socket in a ui event which will probably happen long after that socket has been closed by its creating thread, even if it were still open you would find yourself trying to do a network operation on the UI thread, which will in most configurations cause an exception all by itself.  You need to re-think the whole structure of things, all the way back to the server-client interaction.

Answer (score -1):

This exception and message means that *you* closed the socket and then continued to use it.

Possibly you're unaware that closing either the input or the output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket. You're closing the `ObjectInputStream` at the bottom of that code but you still have the handler running that requires the socket to be open.

Contrary to what you may read elsewhere, it does *not* mean that the peer closed the connection.

NB don't create a new `ObjectOutputStream` per message. You should use the same object input and output streams for the life of the socket, at both ends. Otherwise you will get `StreamCorruptedException.`